# Add product name(s) in WooCommerce New Order Email notification subject

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, orders, email-notifications

I'm looking to change the subject line for the email that goes to shop owner to have product name in.
I saw this code that puts customer first name
how can I adjust this code to have product name

```
/*
 * goes in theme functions.php or a custom plugin
 *
 * Subject filters: 
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_new_order
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_customer_invoice
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_customer_note
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_low_stock
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_no_stock
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_backorder
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_customer_new_account
 *   woocommerce_email_subject_customer_invoice_paid
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 1, 2);

function change_admin_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    $blogname = wp_specialchars_decode(get_option('blogname'), ENT_QUOTES);

    $subject = sprintf( '[%s] New Customer Order (# %s) from Name %s %s', $blogname, $order->id, $order->billing_first_name, $order->billing_last_name );

    return $subject;
}
```

Maybe we just have to change here

```
$subject = sprintf( '[%s] New Customer Order (# %s) from Name %s %s', $blogname, $item->get_name, $order->billing_first_name, $order->billing_last_name );

    return $subject;
}
```

Comment: I haven't used Woocommerce, but it doesn't seem like a good idea to modify core code.  What if they upgrade, and you lose all your changes?

Comment: Here it looks like you can edit emails through the interface: https://woocommerce.com/posts/how-to-customize-emails-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

Your actual code is really outdated… To add the purchased product name(s) *(and quantity)* to the subject of the New Order email notification sent to the admin, use the following:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_new_order', 'change_email_subject_new_order', 10, 2);
function change_email_subject_new_order( $formatted_subject, $order ) {
    $products = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        // Add formatted product name and quantity to the array
        $products[] = sprintf( '%s &times; %d', $item->get_name(), $item->get_quantity() );
    }

    $count    = count($products); // Products count
    $products = implode(', ', $products); // Convert the array to a string

    return sprintf( 
        __('New Customer Order (# %s), %s, from %s %s', 'woocommerce'),  
        $products,
        $order->get_billing_first_name(), 
        $order->get_billing_last_name() 
    );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: this code works great however i want to remove site name and the word "product" i tried to remove it from woocommerce new email order but its still coming, is it par of this code.